# ion-searchbar not triggering my function when using enter button on iOS 13.1

Tags: ios, ionic-framework

I do have this search bar which a couple of days ago it was working, but with the new version of iOS (13.1) now when I use the enter button it does not search, so I'm guessing they change something and now my function does not trigger anymore, this is what I'm using:

```
<ion-searchbar [placeholder]="Search" [formControl]="searchInput" (keyup.enter)="searchItems()"></ion-searchbar>
```

On Android, it's working just fine, any ideas on how to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally solved this problem using keypress instead of keyup and handling the event in the function.

```
<ion-searchbar [placeholder]="Search" [formControl]="searchInput"(keypress)="searchItems($event)"></ion-searchbar>
```

EDIT: This way always enters on the function, to solve this I added a condition:

```
if (event && event.key === "Enter") { // Do stuff}
```

This way I can handle which key is pressed and do whatever I want.

Comment: I run in the same problem. And youre solution helped me too. But the Method is firing now every time i press a key on keyboard. Better Solution? This problem comes with the latest Update of ionic.

Comment: Hey I'm glad it helped you, I edited the main solution, I hope it helps you.

Comment: Thank you for that idea, I'll try it. Just one remark for hydrococcus, it's not because of Ionic. Apple simply stopped supporting  pseudo event key.up enter https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/32963

Comment: This seems to be a fix for: ion-Searchbar with Enter Key NOT working/firing on Firefox browser on PC and Chromium on Raspberry Pi, works otherwise on Chrome PC or Android mobile.